# Post from API with Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't download data from the API

I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(userPassword)
  }),
  observe: 'response' as 'body'
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CoverageService {
  eligibilityUrl = nepalehrUrl + 'EligibilityRequest';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEligibilityData(body:object): Observable<EligibilityResponse> {
    return this.http.post<EligibilityResponse>(this.eligibilityUrl, body, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

I have information:

[image]

Code in component

```
let bodyEligibility = {
  resourceType: "EligibilityRequest",
  patient: {
      reference: "Patient/1975632"
  }
};

this.myEligibilityData$ = this.coverageService.getEligibilityData(bodyEligibility);

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.myEligibilityData$))
```

I am doing something wrong

Comment: Are you aware of the fact, that `btoa` is called not for password, but for login:password?

Answer (score 0):

> Observables are lazy, they won't execute unless you subscribe to them.

So basically you've to `subscribe` to observable in order to make the http call in action. Currently when you do `console.log` you can see thorough observable inside browser `console`. Basically when subscribe to function http call gets executed and underlying `subscribe` function get triggered where you can assign the value of `myEligibilityData`

```
myEligibilityData;

this.coverageService.getEligibilityData(bodyEligibility).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.myEligibilityData = data;
});
```

---

And if you wanted to display this data directly onto the HTML then you can keep your existing code as is. You don't have to `subscribe` observable, instead use `async` pipe on HTML, it will take care of apply `subscribe` and extract data from the `Observable`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myEligibilityData$ | async as myEligibilityData">
   {{myEligibilityData | json}}
</ng-container>
```