# Why is this GET call not hitting the endpoint?

Tags: angular, typescript

My url is correct and other calls I've built using this format has worked but for some reason it never its inside the mapping function and getting a response. I have a C# API layer and that endpoint is never hit. What are possible reasons for this to happen? I've already narrowed down that the url is correct, so what else could be missing? EDIT: IM MAKING A GET CALL, NOT A POST. SORRY IT IS A TYPO

```
getReinstatement(policyNumber: string): Observable<Reinstatement> {
const url = `${this.env.envService().apiUrl}/reinstatement/${policyNumber}`;
return this.http
  .get<any>(url)
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      let reinstatement: Reinstatement = {
        reason: response.reason,
        date: response.date,
        comment: response.comment
      }
      return reinstatement;
    })
  )
```

}

Here is where the code is being called, ngrx structure.

```
this.store.select(selectReinstatement).subscribe(reinstatement => {
  if (!reinstatement) {
    let reinstate: Reinstatement = {
      comment: '',
      date: '',
      reason: ''
    }
    this.reinstatement = reinstate;
    this.buildTabViewbyTab(this.activeTab);
  }
  else {
    this.reinstatement = reinstatement;
    this.buildTabViewbyTab(this.activeTab);
  }
});
```

Here is my controller.

```
namespace PmsClient.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReinstatementController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserHelper _userHelper;
    private readonly AppException _appException;

    private IReinstatementServiceClient _reinstatementService;

    public ReinstatementController(IReinstatementServiceClient reinstatementService)
    {
        _userHelper = new UserHelper();
        _appException = new AppException();

        _reinstatementService = reinstatementService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{policyNumber}")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetReinstatement([FromRoute] string policyNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var serviceResult = await _reinstatementService.GetReinstatement(policyNumber, _userHelper.GetCurrentUserAccessToken(Request), cancellationToken);

                var errorHandler = _appException.ErrorHandler(serviceResult);
                if (errorHandler.StatusCodeId != -1)
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(StatusCode(errorHandler.StatusCodeId, new Message { Code = errorHandler.ErrorCode, Description = errorHandler.ErrorMessages }));
                }

                return await Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(Ok(serviceResult.Result.ToModel().ToResponse()));
            }, cancellationToken);
            return task;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(StatusCode(501, new Message { Code = "FatalError", Description = ex.Message }));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Because you're making `GET` call. change it to POST like this `return this.http.post<any>(url)` should work

Comment: I'm sorry, I am doing a GET, not a POST. That is my typo

Comment: Okay, [how to get data from WebMethod in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58681095/2435473) would help you probably

Comment: what do you get if you console log the response or the error?

Comment: @JSmith I get an error 500.

Comment: @Soulzityr so looks like it is a server erro and your client code is not involved please post your server code.

Comment: @JSmith I edited my post with the controller.

Comment: @Soulzityr I won't be able to help you on this one what is the language? please if you can add another tag to your post for better chance to get answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my controller, I did not configure dependency injection for my service.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke `getReinstatement` method but the HTTP request is not sent, make sure to subscribe to the request. I.e.:

`getReinstatement(10).subscribe()`

or

`getReinstatement(10).toPromise()`

or use the result of the request in *.html via async pipe.

Comment: Well, 10 is just an example parameter to the `getReinstatement` method:) And you put this code whenever you need to call getReinstatement. The point I'm trying to emphasize is that you always need to subscribe to "API calls". Just try it.

Comment: GetReinstatement is already  being called in my code through a select statement following ngrx architecture. The rest of the site is built similarly, do I still need to do this?

Comment: Oh, with NGRX the context becomes more complicated... It's then hard to guess why the request is not sent without having full context. The method implementation you've posted is not enough definitely. So, just for debugging purposes, you can try calling getReinstatement method directly (and subscribe to it as I've mentioned).

Comment: In order to do that, I will need to import my service into the component and then call the method directly right? I don't know if it's a good idea to do all that.

Comment: Yes, you need to import the service. And yes, this is a bad idea for production in your case:) But you can do it for debugging purposes,